# How can I force multiple y-axis in Highcharts to have a common zero when min/max values are not in same ratio above 0 and below 0 for all the y-axis

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

The link mentioned below and the posted code helped me to fix this issue partially but I do see issues when min/max values are not in same ratio above 0 and below 0 for all the y-axis(see the scenario# 2 values).

Scenario# 1: Working when values are something like below

```
Y-Axis 1 - Min/MAX: -750/+750,
Y-Axis 2 - Min/MAX: -10/+10,
Y-Axis 3 - Min/MAX: -1/+1
```

Scenario# 2: See 0's aren't aligned correctly when values are like below

```
Y-Axis 1 - Min/MAX: -1000/+750,
Y-Axis 2 - Min/MAX: -15/+15,
Y-Axis 3 - Min/MAX: -2/+2
```

Can someone please suggest how to fix this issue?

```
yAxis0Extremes = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();
yAxisMaxMinRatio = yAxis0Extremes.max / yAxis0Extremes.min;
yAxis1Extremes = chart.yAxis[1].getExtremes();
yAxis1Min = (yAxis1Extremes.max / yAxisMaxMinRatio).toFixed(0);
chart.yAxis[1].setExtremes(yAxis1Min, yAxis1Extremes.max);
```

[How can I force multiple y-axis in Highcharts to have a common zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086049/how-can-i-force-multiple-y-axis-in-highcharts-to-have-a-common-zero/18933446#18933446)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I force multiple y-axis in Highcharts to have a common zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086049/how-can-i-force-multiple-y-axis-in-highcharts-to-have-a-common-zero)

Comment: nope. can you see the scenario# 2 I mentioned?

Comment: This may be of help: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/2554384-multiple-axis-alignment-control

Comment: createGraph({
        chart: {
            renderTo: container,
            alignThresholds: true,
            events: {},
            type: 'line',
            alignTicks: false
        },
        title: {
            text: charttext
        }......

Comment: I am using reusable creategraph function as I need to draw multiple charts dynamically. I have placed (function (H) {...........}); in  $(document).ready(function () {...........});  and calling creategraph as required..  It is not working. Please suggest if I am missing something or how to achieve this?                         createGraph({
        chart: {
            renderTo: container,
            alignThresholds: true,
            events: {},
            type: 'line',
            alignTicks: false
        },
        title: {
            text: charttext
        }......